# How to increase the highest overshooting bounds for ElasticOutCurve in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

For [ElasticOutCurve](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/ElasticOutCurve-class.html), I would like to increase the highest value of overshooting bounds. I tried to create a custom curve or increasing the period, so far no luck.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's take a look at the source of ElasticOutCurve (from [flutter source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/animation/curves.dart)):

```dart
class ElasticOutCurve extends Curve {
  /// Creates an elastic-out curve.
  ///
  /// Rather than creating a new instance, consider using [Curves.elasticOut].
  const ElasticOutCurve([this.period = 0.4]);

  /// The duration of the oscillation.
  final double period;

  @override
  double transformInternal(double t) {
    final double s = period / 4.0;
    return math.pow(2.0, -10 * t) * math.sin((t - s) * (math.pi * 2.0) / period) + 1.0;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$runtimeType($period)';
  }
}
```

We can see that all they're doing is some basic math.

Here's a graph showing the easing curve from the fluter algorithm:

[image: Chart with flutter algo]

And here's what happens if you multiply the (pow * sin) section by 3:

[image: Chart with x3]

All credit goes to Wolfram Alpha for the charts.

If you played with the different constants you can also adjust it in other ways, although you'll want to make sure it always starts at 0 and ends at 1.

It's unfortunate that the Flutter team didn't make the curve a bit more flexible, but since flutter is open source it's easy enough to copy their curve to make your own.